How ql.optionlet calculates the atm forward, I calculate it manually but I got a different result
**
for example,
2024-06-03 df = 0.977351
2024-09-03 df = 0.966416
And we use the most ez way to calculate it
like this use daycounter act360 manual_atm_forward = (df_start / df_end) ** (1 / t) - 1 = (0.977351/0.966416) ** (360/92) - 1 = 0.045012 and the optionlet atm forward is 0.044277
I don't know why it appeared diff result. My code is as follow：
**
Optionlets Data:
Optionlet 1: Accrual Start: 2024-06-03, Accrual End: 2024-09-03, Price: 37988.360098, ATM Forward: 0.044277, Discount Factor: 0.966416, Standard Deviation: 0.262499, Cap Rate: 0.029115

import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

# Interpolation function: Perform cubic spline interpolation when the strike price does not match
def get_interpolated_volatility(strikes, volatilities, target_strike):
    if len(strikes) != len(volatilities):
        min_len = min(len(strikes), len(volatilities))
        strikes = strikes[:min_len]
        volatilities = volatilities[:min_len]

    strikes = np.array(strikes)
    volatilities = np.array(volatilities)
    mask = ~np.isnan(volatilities)
    filtered_strikes = strikes[mask]
    filtered_volatilities = volatilities[mask]

    if len(filtered_strikes) < 2:
        return filtered_volatilities[0] if len(filtered_volatilities) > 0 else 0.0

    # Use cubic spline interpolation instead of linear interpolation
    interpolation = CubicSpline(filtered_strikes, filtered_volatilities, extrapolate=True)
    return float(interpolation(target_strike))


# Extract Black volatility surface data from black_vol_data
def get_vol_surface_data(black_vol_data):
    expiries = []
    strikes = []
    volatilities = []
    
    black_vol_data['Tenor'] = black_vol_data['Tenor'].astype(str).str.replace('Yr', 'Y').str.replace('yr', 'Y').str.strip()
    for tenor in black_vol_data['Tenor']:
        if 'Y' in tenor:
            expiries.append(ql.Period(int(tenor.replace('Y', '').strip()), ql.Years))
        elif 'M' in tenor:
            expiries.append(ql.Period(int(tenor.replace('M', '').strip()), ql.Months))
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unrecognized tenor format: {tenor}")
    
    strikes = [float(col.replace('%', '')) / 100 for col in black_vol_data.columns[1:]]
    volatilities = (black_vol_data.iloc[:, 1:].values / 100).tolist()

    return expiries, strikes, volatilities

# Create Black CapFloorTermVolSurface
def create_vol_surface_black(black_vol_data):
    expiries, strikes, black_volatility = get_vol_surface_data(black_vol_data)
    volatilities_handles = [
        [ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(v)) for v in row]
        for row in black_volatility
    ]
    vol_surface = ql.CapFloorTermVolSurface(
        0,
        ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE),
        ql.ModifiedFollowing,
        expiries,
        strikes,
        volatilities_handles,
        ql.Actual360()
    )
    return vol_surface, strikes, black_volatility

# Price Cap using Black model
def price_cap_with_black_vol_surface(black_vol_data, discount_handle, ibor_leg, strike, schedule):
    vol_surface, strikes, volatilities_matrix = create_vol_surface_black(black_vol_data)
    
    if strike[0] in strikes:
        expiry_vols = [row[strikes.index(strike[0])] for row in volatilities_matrix]
    else:
        expiry_vols = [
            get_interpolated_volatility(strikes, row, strike[0]) 
            for row in volatilities_matrix
        ]
    interpolated_vol = get_interpolated_volatility(strikes, expiry_vols, strike[0])
    vol_handle = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(interpolated_vol))
    
    # Create Cap and set pricing engine
    cap = ql.Cap(ibor_leg, strike)
    engine_volatility = ql.BlackCapFloorEngine(discount_handle, vol_handle)
    cap.setPricingEngine(engine_volatility)
    
    cap_npv = cap.NPV()
    print(f"\nCap NPV with Black volatility surface: {cap_npv:.6f}")

    # Use Schedule to get accrual_start and accrual_end
    schedule_dates = schedule.dates()
    accrual_start = schedule_dates[:-1]
    accrual_end = schedule_dates[1:]

    # Print detailed information for each cash flow
    print("\nOptionlets Data:")
    optionlets_prices = cap.optionletsPrice()
    optionlets_forward = cap.optionletsAtmForward()
    optionlets_discount_factors = cap.optionletsDiscountFactor()
    optionlets_std_dev = cap.optionletsStdDev()
    cap_rates = cap.capRates()
    
    for i in range(len(optionlets_prices)):
        print(
            f"Optionlet {i+1}: "
            f"Accrual Start: {accrual_start[i].ISO()}, "
            f"Accrual End: {accrual_end[i].ISO()}, "
            f"Price: {optionlets_prices[i]:.6f}, "
            f"ATM Forward: {optionlets_forward[i]:.6f}, "
            f"Discount Factor: {optionlets_discount_factors[i]:.6f}, "
            f"Standard Deviation: {optionlets_std_dev[i]:.6f}, "
            f"Cap Rate: {cap_rates[i]:.6f}"
        )

    return cap_npv

# Set valuation date to December 29, 2023
valuation_date = ql.Date(31, 12, 2023)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = valuation_date

# Build OIS discount curve
discount_handle, discount_curve = build_ois_curve(valuation_date, ois_df)

# Define Cap start and end dates
start_date = ql.Date(3, 6, 2024)
end_date = ql.Date(3, 6, 2029)

# Generate payment dates using Schedule
schedule = ql.Schedule(
    start_date,
    end_date,
    ql.Period(ql.Quarterly),
    ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE),
    ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
    False
)

# Create IborIndex
custom_forward_index = ql.IborIndex(
    "MyIndex",
    ql.Period("1M"),
    0,
    ql.USDCurrency(),
    ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE),
    ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    False,
    ql.Actual360(),
    discount_handle
)

# Populate Fixing data using SOFR data
calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE)
for index, row in sofr_df.iterrows():
    date = ql.Date(row['Date'].day, row['Date'].month, row['Date'].year)
    if calendar.isBusinessDay(date) and date <= valuation_date:
        rate = row['SOFR']
        custom_forward_index.addFixing(date, rate)

# Create IborLeg
ibor_leg = ql.IborLeg([10e6], schedule, custom_forward_index)
strike = [0.029115]

# Price the Cap using Black volatility surface
cap_npv = price_cap_with_black_vol_surface(black_vol_data, discount_handle, ibor_leg, strike, schedule)

# Print payment dates
schedule_dates = schedule.dates()
print("\nOriginal Schedule Dates:")
print([d.ISO() for d in schedule_dates])

df_start = discount_curve.discount(ql.Date(3, 6, 2024))
print(f"Discount factor for 2024-06-03: {df_start:.6f}")


```

